# Compiling google libphonenumber for Javascript

Tags: javascript, ant, google-closure-compiler, libphonenumber

I've followed the directions here:   https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber/tree/master/javascript

However, I run into trouble with this line:

> Build Closure's compiler.jar: ant -f ~/src/closure-compiler/build.xml

There is no `build.xml` in the closure-compiler files I've cloned using git.

Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They've recently switched to using Maven. Ant seems to no longer be supported.  See the instructions under "Building it Yourself" at https://github.com/google/closure-compiler

You can also just download the latest version of the compiler from that page, no need to build with ant or maven.

Answer (score 0):

If you're compiling it for the web, I may also suggest you use a stripped-down pure-javascript alternative which is less than 100 KB (because it's a web browser):

https://github.com/halt-hammerzeit/libphonenumber-js